# python dataframe or hiveSql update based on predecessor value?

Tags: python, sql, scala, pyspark, hive

I have a million in rows that I need to update which looks for the highest count of the predecessor from the same source data and replaces the same value on a different row.

For example.

Original DF.

```
sno Object Name   shape   rating
1   Fruit  apple  round   1.0
2   Fruit  apple  round   2.0
3   Fruit  apple  square  2.5
4   Fruit  orange round   1.5
```

Target DF.

```
sno Object Name   shape rating
1   Fruit  apple  round 1.0
2   Fruit  apple  round 2.0
3   Fruit  apple  round 2.5 <-- automatically detect the difference in shape column and update from square to round
4   Fruit  orange round 1.5
```

Pls advise, how to achieve it in daabrick using either i.e  pyspark or hiveSQL or scala

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly - it sounds like you want to identify delta for existing keys in your source and target.

Pyspark's hash function can help with this.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.hash.html

Once you have identified the delta - many different ways you can handle the merge \ update. Unclear on if you are also looking for how to handle that or not.

#### data set

##### fruit

```
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"apple", "shape":"round","rating":1.0}
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"apple", "shape":"round","rating":2.0}
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"apple", "shape":"square","rating":2.5}
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"orange", "shape":"round","rating":1.5}
```

##### fruit_new

```
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"apple", "shape":"round","rating":1.0}
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"apple", "shape":"round","rating":2.0}
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"apple", "shape":"round","rating":2.5}
{"object": "Fruit", "name":"orange", "shape":"round","rating":1.5}
```

#### sample code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, hash

fruit_df = spark.read.json('tests/data/fruit.json')
fruit_new_df = spark.read.json('tests/data/fruit_new.json')
        
fruit_df = fruit_df.withColumn('hash_value', hash('object', 'name', 'shape', 'rating') )
fruit_new_df = fruit_new_df.withColumn('hash_value', hash('object', 'name', 'shape', 'rating') )

fruit_updates_df = fruit_new_df.alias('fn').join(fruit_df.alias('f'), (\
            (col('fn.object') == col('f.object')) &\
            (col('fn.name') == col('f.name')) &\
            (col('fn.rating') == col('f.rating')) &\
            (col('fn.hash_value') != col('f.hash_value')) \
            ) , how ='inner'
        )

fruit_updates_df.select('fn.object', 'fn.name', 'fn.shape', 'fn.rating' ).show(10,False)
```

#### output

```
+------+-----+-----+------+
|object|name |shape|rating|
+------+-----+-----+------+
|Fruit |apple|round|2.5   |
+------+-----+-----+------+
```